# git on MacOS giving 'early EOF' after exactly 30 seconds of connection open

Tags: git, timeout

This just started happening to me in the last few days. This wasn't happening a month ago. I noticed that I wasn't able to `git pull` a bunch of changes to a git repo. It kept closing the connection. I've timed things, and it seems that exactly 30 seconds after the connection opens, it's automatically closed with an 'early eof' error.

This is an example of the pull attempt:

```
dangoyette$ git pull
remote: Enumerating objects: 4378, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (2125/2125), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (238/238), done.
error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

The only meaningful thing that changed since the last time this was working is that I'm in a different country right now (UK instead of Mexico). However, I haven't had any git issues on my other laptop using the same internet connection.

I tried to update git, thinking maybe this was a bug I could resolve. But when updating git through Homebrew, it seems that's also cloning a repo, and so the Homebrew update attempt fails after 30 seconds as well.

I've tried everything I could find when googling this (using --depth, changing values in .ssh/config and in .gitconfig), but so far nothing has had any impact.

Any thoughts out what would yield such an immediate connection closure after just 30 seconds?

Comment: This ended up being caused by a child safe search filter on the network I'm using that I didn't realize was on. Apparently it kills SSH connections lasting more than 30 seconds. Anyway, this was resolved by turning off the Kids Safe filter. (TalkTalk network).

Comment: `curl` indicates you're using https, not ssh; ssh might actually have been OK, although this kind of filtering software is often lazy and as a result kills things that it shouldn't, so ssh vs https might not have helped either.

Answer (score 0):

Per my comment above, this was the result of child safe browsing filter on the internet provider's network. Bypassing that resolved the issue.